# jQuery Cycle pager append smaller image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

With the following code I am loading in images into a thumbnail pager for a jquery slider on Wordpress.  This works fine but the problem is that its using the huge images and resizing them down to the small size.  This is making my page load slow.  So Ive created a custom image size in the functions.  This creates a new small image called slide-181x86.jpg  .  My question is how do I modify that last line of jquery to add the -181x86 at the end of the url and not at the end of the jpg?  I keep getting slide.jpg-181x86 which obviously isnt right.

Ive been killing myself on this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('.homeslider').cycle({
    speed:  'fast',
    timeout: 7000,
    fx: 'fade',
  slideResize: false,
containerResize: false,
fit:1,
    pager:  '#slitemshome',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
return '<li><a href="#"><img src="'
    + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src')
    + '" width="181" height="86" /></a></li>'; 
}
});
});
</script>
```

edit:

I just tried to do this after the function

```
jQuery('#slitemshome img').attr('src', function(){this.src.replace('.jpg', '-181x86.jpg')})
```

and that doesnt appear to do anything to the url.  Ugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, '-181x86.jpg'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/3hLH4/

---

Originally I was going to find all `img` variables, strip off the `.jpg` ending, and then append `-181x86.jpg` to the end of it, but then I thought, why not just replace the `.jpg` with the `-181x86.jpg` instead?

<sub>P.S. The JSFiddle image won't work as there is no placeholder image with the `-181x86.jpg` appended to the end.</sub>

Comment: I actually have a problem with this now that I am looking at it.  If I use the img selector in your example, it works great, except that it changes the URL of all the images on the page.  I am just trying to target the pager thumbnails.  When I change the img selector to something like '.navthumb img' that doesnt work.  Any suggestions??

Comment: I added the comment above, hope you can help.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, let's say all the images that you want to modify have the class `thumbnail`. Then you would change `img` to `.thumbnail`. Now, if you want to target all the `img` tags within a `div`, you could do something along the lines of `.container img`.

Comment: The answer that @Charlie Charlie posted was indeed the best answer.  The solution was to put the image code further up in the code like so:                  `code`pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    return '<li><a href="#" class="navthumb"><img class="navthumbs" src="'
        + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, '-181x86.jpg')
        + '" width="181" height="86" /></a></li>'; 
}
    });
});`code`

Comment: Edit the comment, and put a ` symbol (above `tab` key on a Mac, called a grave accent) before and after the code (I'd suggest reading up on the Markdown syntax, as you'll need to get used to it now that you're a part of SO! (also, if you feel like upvoting my answer, no problem there ;))).

Comment: `pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { return '<li><a href="#" class="navthumb"><img class="navthumbs" src="' + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, '-181x86.jpg') + '" width="181" height="86" /></a></li>'; } }); }); `